# Which language is easiest to learn?

Tags: java, programming-languages, time, benchmarking

This is a subjective question just to get a general impression. As Java is the most popular programming language right now it is used as a benchmark.

Lets say I have to spend T amount of time/effort to learn/master Java. By what factor should I multiply T to get a time/effort needed to learn/master other language instead, say C, C++, C#, python, perl, Lisp, Haskel, PHP?

My guess is:

```
0.5T PHP
0.9T python
1.1T C#
2.0T C++
3.0T C
```

What do you think?

Comment: Lesson - do not ask subjective questions on SO...

Comment: I'm surprised that you think C is 50% "harder" than C++. But if it's subjective, then whatever numbers you come up with will be meaningless.

Comment: I think this question is subjective and argumentative.  Learning and mastering are both subjective.  There are far too many variables to be able to do this adequately.  Flagged.

Comment: Depends on how easily you grasp different concepts.  If you just don't get pointers, for example, C could take 1000x as long to learn as Java.

Comment: If you don't get pointers, you'll also spend your entire Java life wondering why saying `Object a = b` (where b is an Object) and then doing stuff to `a` causes `b` to act all funny and like try and mimic `a`...

Comment: The easiest would be silence. You don't even have to say anything to mean yes.

Comment: @In silico:  The evaluation of C as harder than C++ makes sense.  If you use modern C++, there's a lot of stuff you simply don't have to bother with much.  If you're talking about learning the whole language, then C++ is far harder.  If you're talking about learning enough to get by, and how to write programs, C++ can be easier.

Comment: I don't believe vad can claim "mastery" of Java.  The ecosystem is like the known universe:  expands faster than the speed of light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dartmouth BASIC was designed to be easy to learn and easy to use.  For what it did, it was a howling success on both counts.

MIT used Scheme (dialect of LISP) in course 6.001 for many years, and concluded that it was a lot easier to learn, at least initially, because there was essentially no syntax to trip students up.

Back in the late Steam Era, when mainframe dinosaurs still ruled the Earth, the UT Austin Computer Science Department did side-by-side tests, teaching FORTRAN to some of the freshman and PASCAL to others.  Their conclusion was that PASCAL's pickier syntax was INITIALLY harder to learn, but the PASCAL students consistently spent less computer time, and less runs (batch processing, punched cards), getting their homework running, even though their homework assignments were typically harder.

C and C++ have very, very similar core languages.  90% of the code you write will be identical in all four languages, after allowing for personal taste in design and naming conventions.  C doesn't really have anything above the core language, while C++ adds classes and templates.  I'm not familiar with C# or Java, beyond a rudimentary feeling that they both started with C and went from there.

Ada was, in my personal experience, not difficult to learn, and the compilers were picky enough that syntactically-correct code generally worked as intended on the first try.  Other people have also noticed that property of Ada.

Comment: Mainframe dinosaurs still rules the Earth.  Just ask your bank.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I'd suggest [Brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck). It's my favourite language for beginners. Don't worry, the name is joke!

Comment: +1. I highly recommend this language for beginners as well. It has few keywords to memorize, and you don't have to deal with advanced concepts like pointers, OOP etc that are built into some of the less beginner-friendly languages like C++ or Java.

Comment: you should only go for prime numbers for rep.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen, Brilliant idea! Unfortunately, the next prime number is 4 away... 1549 is prime though, and thats 42 away. I can do that. Accept my one unaccepted question, and get 4 more upvotes... Plus, I mean, 42. Awesome.

Comment: that's easy.  Get upvotes, and then downvote others (-1) until you have reached full primality.

Answer (score 2):

This is so subjective that it cannot be answered. It totally depends on what you need to do with the language.

Comment: So, why did you answer it?

Comment: Rep whoring.  I do it too on occasion.  :)

Comment: Hoping to get some easy reputation :)

Comment: Or, maybe he's out to ruin other peoples reputation. For example, whoever just downvoted him lost **one whole point**!